# Why isnt my eventlistener not working eventhough it is selected and written right?

Tags: javascript

i have a express app built with mongoDB and nodejs.I have linked a main javascript file.There are multiple pages in this project.The eventlisteners are working in all other pages except one page.
This is the code for the 'a' tag for which i have added a event listener which isnt working

```
<a href="" id="test">Listeners Test</a>
```

and this is the javascript side of things

```
const test=document.getElementById("test");

    test.addEventListener("click",function(){
  alert("you clicked me");
})
```

and im linking a image in which you can see that the 'a' tag is succesfully selected in javascript.
['a' tag is succesfully selected in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxMzh.png)

Comment: You've blocked `alert` on the page? Try to log the message to the console instead.

Comment: Try to replace `alert` with `console.log` and check console if anything is logged on click.

Comment: i did do that @palaѕн that also isnt working

Comment: the problem is oly with this one page ..all the other pages which have event listeners are working fine ..

Comment: have you tried just console in the js file? may you has connected js file to the html in a wrong way.